# Is there a way to make a mobile browser to open a pdf and not to download it

Tags: html, pdf, mobile

I know that simple mobile browsers don't have the feature to make this, but I want that a smartphone could open a link to a pdf file. This is important because I want to open pdf in a given page like this:

```
<a href="teste.pdf#page=4">Open page 4</a>
```

This works on chrome and firefox, but when in mobile it just downloads the pdf.

I'm using bootstrap.

Comment: It totally, and *only*, depends on whether the browser itself or its PDF-reading extension supports the syntax. "Wanting that it could" is a Feature Request, not a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be by converting it to html5 / html4 using FlexPaper. There are multiple options including open source options. Have a look here:

http://flexpaper.devaldi.com